# Why datalocalization is not applicable for sort and shuffle phase in Map Reduce process?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I came to know that `datalocalization` is applicable only in mapper phase which means it will keep the output of mapper in `temp` [configured in `mapred-site.xml` in local file system] folder in order to handle network failure.

But this process [`datalocalization`] is not applicable for `reducer phase` means the output of reducer is not saved in local file system [LFS], why it is not required to store reducer output to LFS?

Answer (score 0):

During mapper phase of `MapReduce` the output `[part-m-xxxx]` will be stored in the local file system to avoid any network related issues this is called as `datalocalization`.

But the reducer output is not stored in the local file system because:

1. Even if something went wrong in the reducer phase it will get data
   from worker/ data node using `RPC`.
2. If reducer phase `[part-r-xxxx]` is successful then it is a final output, 
   so it does not make sense to store the final output as well in the
   local file system and waste the disk storage.